# PostgreSQL Total of Count & Sum Summary Line Formatting

Tags: postgresql, count, sum

I have a Postgres query I am working out where I join two tables.

One table is a 'contract' table that has contract_json JSON attributes stored in a JSONB column which stores the amount.

The other table 'contract_folks' stores all of the individual(s) that are part of the contract and can relate back to a contract by contract_id.

Here is the query I have so far:

```sql
SELECT 
contract_folks.name AS "Financier"
,contract.contract_json->>'contractor' as "Contractor
,COUNT(contract.id) as "Count of Contracts by Contractor"
,SUM((contract.contract_json->>'amount')::float8::numeric::money) as "Total Dollars Per Contractor"
FROM contract
JOIN contract_folks on contract.id = contract_folks.document_id
WHERE 1=1
AND contract_folks.folk_type = 1 -- 'contractors' (type 0 is financiers in contract_folks table)
GROUP BY  contract_folks.name, contract.contract_json->>'lead_provider'
ORDER BY contract_folks.name ASC
```

The results end up looking like this:

[image: (Current Results)]

I would like for the Financier column to only show the Financier name just once and the rest blank like so with a total (of count and sum) lines for each (not sure if this is possible by modifying my query or if it would be better to use a function?):

[image: (Desired Results)]

If this is a duplicated question then please point me in the right direction and I will be grateful!  Also, thank you for taking a look and any help/suggestions offered are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grouping sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) to do the subtotals for you.

```
with roll as (
  SELECT contract_folks.name AS financier,
         contract.contract_json->>'contractor' as contractor,
         COUNT(contract.id) as contract_count,
         SUM((contract.contract_json->>'amount')::float8::numeric::money) 
            as contractor_dollars,
         GROUPING(contract_folks.name, contract.contract_json->>'lead_provider')
            as grp_map
    FROM contract
    JOIN contract_folks on contract.id = contract_folks.document_id
   WHERE 1=1
     AND contract_folks.folk_type = 1 -- 'contractors' (type 0 is financiers in contract_folks table)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(contract_folks.name, contract.contract_json->>'lead_provider')
)
select case 
         when grp_map = 1 then 'TOTAL FOR '||financier,
         when grp_map = 3 then 'GRAND TOTAL'
         when financier = lag(financier) over (order by financier, contractor, grp_num) then null
         else financier
       end as "Financier",
       contractor as "Contractor",
       contract_count as "Count of Contracts by Contractor",
       contract_dollars as "Total Dollars Per Contractor"
  from roll
 order by financier, contractor, grp_num;
```

If you do not want the `GRAND TOTAL` line, then exclude it with `WHERE grp_num != 3` in the final query.

If you want percentages, join back into the rollup for financier-level dollars and the grand total with something like this:

```
with roll as (
  SELECT contract_folks.name AS financier,
         contract.contract_json->>'contractor' as contractor,
         COUNT(contract.id) as contract_count,
         SUM((contract.contract_json->>'amount')::float8::numeric::money) 
            as contractor_dollars,
         GROUPING(contract_folks.name, contract.contract_json->>'lead_provider')
            as grp_map
    FROM contract
    JOIN contract_folks on contract.id = contract_folks.document_id
   WHERE 1=1
     AND contract_folks.folk_type = 1 -- 'contractors' (type 0 is financiers in contract_folks table)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(contract_folks.name, contract.contract_json->>'lead_provider')
)
select case 
         when d.grp_map = 1 then 'TOTAL FOR '||d.financier,
         when d.grp_map = 3 then 'GRAND TOTAL'
         when d.financier = lag(d.financier) over (order by d.financier, d.contractor, d.grp_num) then null
         else d.financier
       end as "Financier",
       d.contractor as "Contractor",
       d.contract_count as "Count of Contracts by Contractor",
       d.contract_dollars as "Total Dollars Per Contractor",
       case 
         when d.grp_num = 0 then 100.0 * d.contract_dollars / f.contract_dollars 
         else null
       end as "Share within Financier",
       case 
         when d.grp_num != 3 then 100.0 * d.contract_dollars / g.contract_dollars
         else null
       end as "Share of Grand Total"
  from roll d
  left join roll f on f.financier = d.financier and f.grp_num = 1
  left join roll g on g.grp_num = 3
 order by d.financier, d.contractor, d.grp_num;
```

Comment: That query really is helpful.  Thank you so much!  May I ask how would you go about adding a percentage of the grand total but only to each row with a contractor?

Comment: @finiteloop  I added an example of how I have done this before.

Comment: that works really well!  The only thing I am running into now is that the grand total line is not present any longer.  Do you have an idea of why that may be?

Comment: Yes.  I do.  It's because the joins dropped it out.  I updated the answer.  Those should be left outer joins.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That works really well and I appreciate your help and effort!

Answer (score 0):

This sample aims to concentrate on two relevant parts of the problem of this question: Adding a total line for each group and showing the grouped column content only once.

The query is split into two parts which is connected by a union.

First part uses the window function row number to output the financier name only in the first row of a group.

Second part is a ordinary GROUP BY with a column prefixed with 'TOTALS FOR' the result of the UNION is ordered by the financier name and the id, so that the total line always appears under the rows of that financier.

Try it here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qJfH4WYjABuw7MppVLHYFi/0

```
CREATE TABLE so63025001 (
  id serial,
  financier text,
  contractor text,
  contractcount int,
  total_dollars int);
  
INSERT INTO so63025001 (financier, contractor, contractcount, total_dollars)
VALUES
('MR MONOPOLY', 'XYZ Construction', 1, 22000),
('MR MONOPOLY', 'ABC Construction', 2, 22000),
('MR MONOPOLY', '1234 Construction', 10, 22000),
('RICHIE RICH', 'XYZ Construction', 2, 550000),
('RICHIE RICH', 'ABC Construction', 3, 22000),
('RICHIE RICH', '1234 Construction', 5, 22000); 

SELECT name, contractor, contractcount, total_dollars  FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY financier) = 1 
            THEN financier 
            ELSE '' END AS name, 
       financier, contractor, contractcount, total_dollars, id
FROM so63025001
UNION ALL
-- total line
SELECT 'TOTALS FOR ' || financier AS NAME, financier, '', sum(contractcount), sum(total_dollars), 
       -- make sure it is the last record
       sum(id) as id
FROM so63025001
GROUP BY financier) sub 
-- take care of the right order
ORDER BY financier, id;
```